# How to enable TLS 1.2 for API call in ASP.NET 2.0 application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, authorize.net, tls1.2

Our ASP.NET 2.0 website processes credit card transactions via calls to Authorize.Net's API. Authorize has informed us that on a date certain, to be announced, our client *must* utilize TLS 1.2 protocol for API calls.

Microsoft seemed to indicate that a solution is available in this 10-22-16 KB article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154517/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-.net-framework-2.0-sp2-on-windows-vista-sp2-and-server-2008-sp2

> ...we have added the SslProtocolsExtensions enumeration that you can
>   use as an option for setting TLS v1.2, TLS v1.1, as well as operating
>   system defaults for the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol property
>   when targeting **.NET framework version 2.0 SP2**.

Please note that, despite the title of this article, the quote above does *not* refer to Windows Vista SP2 or Windows 2008 SP2 operating systems, since those operating systems do not support TLS v1.1 and 1.2.

I have implemented and tested my understanding of the solution indicated in the KB article by taking the following steps:

1. Enabled TLS 1.2 on our Windows Server 2008 R2 web server (and confirmed via ssllabs.com).
2. Confirmed that SP2 was, in fact, installed for .NET framework version 2.0.
3. Added the two source files shown in the referenced KB article to our project (i.e., SecurityProtocolTypeExtensions.cs and SslProtocolsExtensions.cs)
4. Entered the following line of code (from the KB article) to the project just above the API call: System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolTypeExtensions.Tls12;

Unfortunately, when running the application, I encounter the following error on the line of code shown in item #3 above:

> System.NotSupportedException: The requested security protocol is not
>   supported.

At this point, I am stumped. I'd especially appreciate any insights on how to move forward with this solution, but am interested in learning about any other approaches that you're aware of to allow an API call from an ASP.NET 2.0 application to utilize TLS 1.2. (Upgrading to a more recent version of the .NET framework is a last resort.)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 17):

We had to migrate to TLS 1.2 with our .NET 2.0 app and we didn't want to port the code to .NET 4.5/4.6.  After a few days of research and after coming across this post we found the solution.  This post references the wrong HOTFIX.  To get TLS 1.2 working for .NET 2.0 on Server 2008 R2 you need this HOTFIX: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154518/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-.net-framework

It references 3.5.1 framework but ALSO works for 2.0 framework.  Once the hotfix is installed you can either make registry changes on the server as indicated OR make code changes in your app to reference TLS 1.2 directly.

C#
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

VB
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072,System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)

For other OS's check out Troy Starr's post here:
https://community.qualys.com/thread/16917-net-framework

Hope this helps

Comment: This solution still works in 2020 if anyone needs it like I did :)

Comment: Works in 2022..

Comment: It looks to me that only the 2 registry keys have to be set. I didn't have to install any update, just add modify the registry.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else that finds this thread, I was able to get TLS 1.2 to work on .Net 3.5, using the same steps (#1-#4) detailed in the original question above.  Once I applied the patch to the Win 2012 server (which my shared hosting company was nice enough to apply), then added the line of code to enable TLS 1.2 before my API call, it worked right away:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolTypeExtensions.Tls12;
```

Comment: Using VS 2008 with .net 3.5; this didn't work for me until I defined the constant Tls12; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44893192/2559297

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is a bit old - but for the help of others this worked for us - and our Authorize.Net transactions now work with TLS 1.2 on our .NET 2.0 AbleCommerce application. [It looks like the transition deadline for production has been extended until February 28, 2018]

Environment: Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5, AbleCommerce 7.0.2 build 11659, CommerceBuilder.AuthorizeNet 7.0.9764.0

As per @JoeBoxer's answer above, [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154518/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the--net-framework) did the trick - specifically setting the two registry keys for our x64 based system (the patch listed would not install on our box):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
```

We also did [this](https://tecadmin.net/enable-tls-on-windows-server-and-iis/) - as we did not have the entries for TLS 1.2 - but this alone did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

AS TLS 1.2 doesn't support asp.net 2.0. 
There is an alternate way to implement TLS 1.2 without migrating project from asp.net 2.0 to the latest/higher version. Following are the steps:

1. Create a new separate project in asp.net higher version.
2. Add new Web Service or WebAPI(Later we will consume it in the main project).
3. Write down a particular code here and call particular API which needs to validate with TLS 1.2.
4. Now Deploy this web service/WebAPI and consume in the main project.

Below is sample code:

```
[WebMethod]
        public LoginResult TestLogin(string _username, string _password, string _tokenID)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)3072;
                LoginResult _loginResult = new LoginResult();
                _loginResult = _sForceRef.login(_username, _password + _tokenID);
                return _loginResult;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
Reference
namespace System.Net
{
    [System.Flags]
    public enum SecurityProtocolType
    {
       Ssl3 = 48,
       Tls = 192,
       Tls11 = 768,
       Tls12 = 3072,
    }
}
```