# How to implement Security Protocols TLS 1.2 in .Net 3.5 framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, paypal, tls1.2

As Paypal updated their response, I need to update security protocols TLS to v1.2 in my existing application which is on .NET 3.5 framework. 
What changes required to update this in existing code, I cannot update the application to newer framework.

Answer (score 24):

I'm using VS 2008 with .net 3.5.30729.4926. All I had to do was:

Add imports:

```
Imports System.Security.Authentication
Imports System.Net
```

Add this to my code (C#):

```
public const SslProtocols _Tls12 = (SslProtocols)0x00000C00;
public const SecurityProtocolType Tls12 = (SecurityProtocolType)_Tls12;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12;
```

VB.net version:

```
Const _Tls12 As SslProtocols = DirectCast(&HC00, SslProtocols)
Const Tls12 As SecurityProtocolType = DirectCast(_Tls12, SecurityProtocolType)
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12

Dim wbrq As HttpWebRequest
Dim wbrs As HttpWebResponse
Dim sw As StreamWriter
Dim sr As StreamReader
Dim strResult As String

'Create a new HttpWebRequest object.
wbrq = WebRequest.Create(strURL)
wbrq.Method = "POST"
wbrq.ContentLength = DataString.Length
wbrq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

'upload data
sw = New StreamWriter(wbrq.GetRequestStream)
sw.Write(DataString)
sw.Close()

'get response
wbrs = wbrq.GetResponse
sr = New StreamReader(wbrs.GetResponseStream)
strResult = sr.ReadToEnd.Trim
sr.Close()
```

Comment: @Cullub Thanks. I suspect MS might retrofit the constant in older versions of .net.

Comment: This is better than the other answer at the moment - it doesn't depend on a broken link ;-)

Comment: Where in the code was this placed? In a class? or global.asax? etc?

Comment: @Anna The SecurityProtocol is set immediately before making a HttpWebRequest. See my edited post above.

Comment: Just to confirm, did you have to apply any hotfix and edit the registry to enable TLS 1.2 on the server? Or is it just using the code mentioned above?

Comment: @Anna No hotfixes or registry edits. Just the code above. YMMV

Comment: Just `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)0x00000C00;` for a C# project was sufficient for me.

Comment: You code save me :d. Thank you very much. Net 2.0 can use this code.

Answer (score 3):

just adding adding Your code in vb .net 3.5 version :

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
```

then Your code become :

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072, SecurityProtocolType)

Dim wbrq As HttpWebRequest
Dim wbrs As HttpWebResponse
Dim sw As StreamWriter
Dim sr As StreamReader
Dim strResult As String

'Create a new HttpWebRequest object.
wbrq = WebRequest.Create(strURL)
wbrq.Method = "POST"
wbrq.ContentLength = DataString.Length
wbrq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
.............
```

hope this help

Answer (score 2):

If you are on NET 3.5.1 you have an option of applying a rollup hotfix and apply a registry edit to tell .NET to use the system default.
[More details here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154518/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-.net-framework-3.5.1-on-windows-7-sp1-and-server-2008-r2-sp1)

Failing that you need to be using .NET 4.5 for TLS 1.2 & 1.1 support and on Windows Server 2008 R2 at a minimum.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Add de following code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

[More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient)