# The underlying connection was closed. Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: vb.net, ssl-certificate, asmx, ss

I am using VB.NET 2.0 and my server is Windows Server 2005, XP operating system.

I am facing this error on server:

> The underlying connection was closed. Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

And not in my local environment which has Windows 7 operating system .

Can anyone help in this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the table at [Support for SSL/TLS protocols on Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2011/10/02/support-for-ssltls-protocols-on-windows/) that Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP only support TLS 1.0; they do not natively support TLS 1.1 or later.

You can either look for third-party software to enable the use of the required TLS version or abandon the use of Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP.

Comment: How to check which version of the certificate is using by the server?

Comment: [How do we determine the SSL/TLS version of an HTTP request?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100029/how-do-we-determine-the-ssl-tls-version-of-an-http-request)

Comment: Is there any solution in coding using vb.net 2.0 ?

Comment: You really should try to get your employer to allow you access to google.com. [How to enable TLS 1.2 for API call in ASP.NET 2.0 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863129/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-for-api-call-in-asp-net-2-0-application)